# write to a json file on a meteor app

Tags: json, node.js, meteor, fs

I have been trying to run a little scrap on meteor using x-ray. I need to output some data on a json file. 
It works on node and express, but not on meteor.

The thing is, when i tried to console.log the results, it did what was supposed to do. So i tried to print something on a Json file using file system.
The same happened: print to the console, not to the file.

Is the path to the file the problem?

here's the scraper:

```
import Xray from 'x-ray';

var xray = new Xray();

xray('http://reddit.com/r/meteor/', '.title',
[{
  title: '',
  href: '@href'
}])
  .write('result.json');
```

also tried ('./result.json')

this actually works:

```
import Xray from 'x-ray';

var xray = new Xray();

xray('http://google.com', 'title')(function(err, title) {
  console.log(title) // Google
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing to the file system from Meteor isn't a good idea. Basically in development mode you will trigger a recompile of your code, which isn't helpful. In production you won't have ready access to the file system.

It is possible to define a path that you have access to, and use fs to write files, but generally it is best practice to write to the database (especially json data). Even image files can be stored in MongoDB.

You can push files out to Amazon S3 using the AWS SDK.